# Rails 3: Multiply each char of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Given a string `@t = "123456789"`, how can I cycle each char of the string and multiply it by a defined number?

I've tried `@t[0].to_i * number`.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@t = "123456789".split(//)
@t[0].to_i * number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the each_char block method:

```
num = 2
@t = "123456789"
@t.each_char {|ch| puts(ch.to_i * num) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@t.chars{|c| puts c.to_i * 5 }
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to print them out then this works.

```
@t.chars {|c| puts c.to_i * number}
```

If you are wanting to make it a new string then

```
@t.chars.map { |c| c.to_i  * number }.join
```

Some References that may help you.

For the first .chars method in http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html

For the second .chars returns a enumerator that .map can be called on.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html

Hope this helps.